# Выборка данных многие ко многим

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Имеется две сущности:

Cargo:

```
@Entity
public class Cargo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "activity")
    private String activity;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "cargo_number")
    private String cargoNumber;

    @Column(name = "cargo_type")
    private String cargoType;

    @Column(name = "out_bound_truck")
    private String outBoundTruck;

    @Column(name = "in_bound_truck")
    private String inBoundTruck;

    @Column(name = "master_cargo")
    private String masterCargo;

    @Column(name = "content_type")
    private String contentType;

    @Column(name = "supplier")
    private String supplier;

    @Column(name = "consignee")
    private String consignee;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "master_cargo_fk", nullable = false)
    private MasterCargo masterCargos;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "cargo_inbound_trucks",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cargos_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "inbound_trucks_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<InboundTruck> inboundTrucks;

}
```

InbooundTruck:

```
@Entity
public class InboundTruck {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "activity")
    private String activity;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "truckNumber")
    private String truckNumber;

    @Column(name = "trailerNumber")
    private String  trailerNumber;

    @Column(name = "driverName")
    private String driverName;

    @Column(name = "carrier")
    private String carrier;

    @Column(name = "supplier")
    private String supplier;

    @Column(name = "comments")
    private String comments;

    @Column(name = "arrivalTimePlan")
    private Date arrivalTimePlan;

    @Column(name = "arrivalTimeFact")
    private Date arrivalTimeFact;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "inboundTrucks")
    private Set<Cargo> cargos;
}
```

Они связаны в БД таблицей CargoInboundTruck по Cargo_Id и InboundTruckId соответственно

так же есть контроллер для показа информации о машинах через ID

```
@GetMapping("/load/{id}")
public String loadEdit(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model){
    if(!inboundTruckRepository.existsById(id)){
        return "load";
    }
    Optional<InboundTruck> inboundTruck = inboundTruckRepository.findById(id);
    InboundTruck inboundTruck1 = inboundtruckService.findByCargo(id);
    ArrayList<InboundTruck> res = new ArrayList<>();
    inboundTruck.ifPresent(res :: add);
    model.addAttribute("inboundTruck1", inboundTruck1);
    model.addAttribute("inboundTruck", res);
    return "loadtrucks";
}
```

и сервис :

```
InboundTruck addInboundTruck(InboundTruck inboundTruck);
void delete(Long id);
InboundTruck getByNumber(String number);
InboundTruck editInboundTruck(InboundTruck inboundTruck);
InboundTruck findByCargo(Long id);
List<InboundTruck> getAll();
Optional<InboundTruck> getById(Long id);
```

Подскажите, как осуществить метод findByCargo() что бы данные о cargo подтягивались из таблицы CargoInboundTruck по ID

Answer (score 0):

> данные о cargo подтягивались из таблицы CargoInboundTruck по ***ID***

Замените в сервисе метод  `findByCargo()` на `findCargoById(Long id)`

Comment: поправил пост, спасибо, но тут больше интересует как реализовать метод через @query